# Convert polar form to rectangular form

Tags: complex-numbers

> Using DeMoivre's Theorem, express $\left( \cos \frac{\pi}{3} + i \sin \frac{\pi}{3} \right)^7 $ in the form of $ \cos x + i \sin x$ and $ x + iy$

my work: using the theorem, $\left( \cos \frac{7\pi}{3} + i \sin \frac{7\pi}{3} \right) $

That answers the first part, the next part in rectangular form:

I changed $\left( \cos \frac{7\pi}{3} + i \sin \frac{7\pi}{3} \right) $ to $\left( \cos \frac{\pi}{3} + i \sin \frac{\pi}{3} \right)$

I plot it on an argand diagram showing $\sin \frac{\pi}{3} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

The $x$ value is $1$ and $y$ value is $\sqrt{3}$

Therefore, it is $1+i\sqrt{3}$

However, my answer is wrong, the answer is $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt3}{2}i$

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: "The $x$ value is 1 and y value is $\sqrt{3}$. How did you get there? You computed $\sin \frac{\pi}{3}$, the imaginary component of $\cos \frac{\pi}{3} + i \sin \frac{\pi}{3}$, and got the correct answer of $\sqrt{3}/2$. How did it become $\sqrt{3}$?

Comment: @TheoBendit i drew it on an argand diagram, the x axis (real) is 1 and the y axis (imaginary) is $\sqrt{3}$

Comment: You might as well forget about the argand diagram  and stick with the answer $x=1/2$, $y={\sqrt3}/2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct up to plot on Argand diagram, but, to covert to rectangular form you must find $\cos(\frac \pi 3)$ and $\sin(\frac \pi 3)$ which is $\frac A H$ and $\frac O H$ respectively.

You have just taken the sides of the triangle instead of the ratios.
To put it another way, the sides you have used are for a 1-2-$\sqrt 3$ triangle. The hypotenuse (2) is **not** the radius of a unit circle so you cannot just use the side lengths.

Answer (score 0):

For polar angle  $\pi/3$ or its co-terminal angle  $7\pi/3$ consider right triangle of Argand diagram of the complex plane.

From polar form $r= 1\cdot e^{i \theta}$  rectangular form conversion has two components/coordinates $(x,y)= (r \cos \theta, r\sin \theta).$ In the latter case,

the opposite side is $\sqrt3/2$, adjacent side is $ \frac12$, hypotenuse length is $1$ or one unit.

The opposite side is not $\sqrt3$, adjacent side is not $ 1$, hypotenuse length is *not* $2.$